# Не работает консоль на определенном сайте

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Делаю проект на node.js, express, handlebars. Использую TypeScript. Запускаю сервер на 3000 порте. В консоли не отображается console.log (ни в одном браузере), но в терминале печатает. На других сайтах все работает

Answer (score 0):

Напишите в консоли просто `console.log` (то есть мы просто смотрим функцию а е вызываем ее).

Если вы увидите `ƒ (){}`  - значит кто-то переопредилил консоль, чтоб скрыть любой вывод в консоль. Обычно его добавляют только для продакшн кода, но зависит от настроек сборщика.

Если же вы видите `ƒ log() { [native code] }` - значит консоль работает нормально и проблема в другом месте.

Comment: Chrome выводит: `ƒ`
Firefox: `function log()`

Comment: @Ermolaev.ID а если просто написать в консоль console.log(...), оно сработает? Или консоль вообще не работает?

Comment: `console.log("Работает")`
`Работает`
`undefined`

Comment: Если вы пишете на Node.js, то в браузере в консоли оно и не появится. Оно должно быть в консоли сервера - в командном окне или IDE

Comment: Почему тогда на других моих проектах (тоже Node.js) консоль прекрасно работает. Но на них использую webpack, может в нем дело?

Answer (score 0):

В консоли броузера будут отображаться сообщения, которые выводятся кодом, выполняющимся в броузере (на стороне клиента). Если console.log() выполняется на стороне сервера, то и вывод будет в консоли сервера.